# Show element if no class is present in UL LI

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which filters a list of LI

```
function searchCourse() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("courseFilter");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("gallery");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].classList.add("active");
        } else {
            li[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
    } 
}
```

What I want to do now is when the user types in the box, if none of the LI items have the class active it should remove a class called hidden to the following div:

```
<div class="calendar-occasion__no-results hidden" id="no-results">No courses found. We are always adding new events to our calendar.<br /> Please register your interest by <a href="@Model.ContactUs.LinkUrl">getting in touch with us</a></div>
```

The script should be active for each time a user types in the filter box and if there is more than 1 LI with class active it goes and adds the hidden class back to the div.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Your script works if you add the onkeyup handler as described below. Do keep in mind that because you use `indexOf()`, any position suffices. So if you have 3 courses named 'mathematics', 'data science', and 'sociology', then typing the letter 's' will not hide anything. Typing 'a' will only hide 'sociology'. This might be as intended, but if you're trying to mimic suggestions, using `startsWith()` might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `onkeyup` event of the `input` element, and inside the function just check the number of the active `li` items:

```html
<script>
  function checkActiveItems() {
    alert("do the checking");
  }
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkActiveItems()" />
```